Passing Bundle arguments to a fragment and invalidating arguments afterwards
I have two entry points into my fragment: one without passing a Bundle and a second that does pass a Bundle with an argument. I noticed, that once I've passed it an argument, the fragment retains that argument and that when I navigate to the fragment without passing an argument, the argument is still present.
I tried setting arguments to null:
    barcode = NO_BARCODE
    arguments?.let {
        barcode = it.getString(SaleFragment.BARCODE, NO_BARCODE)
        createNewDbItemDialog().show()
        arguments = null
    }

That however has the undesired side effect that no arguments will ever be received by this fragment any more, even when I navigate to it with an argument:
            findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                .navigate(
                    R.id.products_fragment,
                    Bundle().apply { putString(BARCODE, barcode) },
                    NavOptions.Builder()
                        .setPopUpTo(R.id.sale_fragment, inclusive = false, saveState = true)
                        .setRestoreState(true)
                        .build()
                )

The barcode argument is not received any more. Only the first time, after which arguments is set to null.
How can I reliably distinguish in my fragment whether or not an argument was passed along when navigating to it?
Update
I've tried to use a dedicated flag for whether or not to show the dialog:
    barcode = NO_BARCODE
    arguments?.let {
        if (it.getBoolean(SaleFragment.ShowDialog, false)) {
            barcode = it.getString(SaleFragment.BARCODE, NO_BARCODE)
            createNewDbItemDialog().show()
            //it.putBoolean(SaleFragment.ShowDialog, false)
            it.remove(SaleFragment.ShowDialog)
        }
    }

but I'm experiencing the same behavior. I'm beginning to suspect, that Bundle arguments simply don't work the way I expect them to. That would mean that I have to refactor my app's navigation to not rely on something that isn't there.
As such, I am seeking a thorough explanation of how Bundle arguments work and particularly the reason why what I'm trying to do doesn't work and cannot work. Thus, at this point I'm not looking for a solution to the initial question any more, because it seems like there isn't one.
Minimal reproducible sample:
In Android Studio, create a new project "Navigation Drawer Views Activity". Then in HomeFragment, in onCreateView, paste the following code above return root:
    textView.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
            .navigate(
                R.id.nav_gallery,
                Bundle().apply {
                    putBoolean("ShowDialog", true)
                    putString("BARCODE", "12345678")
                },
                NavOptions.Builder()
                    .setPopUpTo(R.id.nav_home, inclusive = false, saveState = true)
                    .setRestoreState(true)
                    .build()
            )
    }

and in GalleryFragment, again in onCreateView right above return root, this:
    arguments?.let {
        if (it.getBoolean("ShowDialog", false)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setTitle("Barcode")
                .setMessage(it.getString("BARCODE", "oops..."))
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                .create()
                .show()
            //it.putBoolean("ShowDialog", false)
            it.remove("ShowDialog")
        }
    }

That's it. Now when you navigate to GalleryFragment from the Drawer navigation, there should be no dialog. But when you tap on "This is home Fragment", the dialog should be presented. However, with this code, the dialog only shows the first time when navigating to GalleryFragment with a tap on "This is home Fragment". In subsequent times, the dialog is not shown.

"How can I reliably distinguish in my fragment whether or not an argument was passed along when navigating to it?" - can't you just use a default or null value?

@dominicoder what do you mean by that?

Looks like there's an answer and you updated to try what I was suggesting. If you can post a project that is a minimal reproducible sample, I'd take a look out of curiosity.

@dominicoder I hope this counts as an minimal reproducible sample

Ideally a minimal sample is a complete project set up with everything configured (SDK versions, gradle settings, library dependency versions, etc) to illustrate the issue so someone need only open it and run ...

That said, I gave it a shot and for me the nav drawer doesn't do any navigation out of the box (which seems like a bug), so I wired the fab to navigate without a bundle. What I found is that that dialog is shown consistently on tapping the text and going back and tapping again. BUT if I tap the fab (to navigate without args) after already being on the gallery, and hit back, then neither tapping the fab or the text navigates to the gallery (stays on "This is home Fragment"). IDK if this is what you're seeing, but also feel like a bug given how little I did to the code template.

Hm.. on the minimal sample, I don't think a complete Android project would fit into a question. After all, there's a lot of boilerplate stuff involved. And even if, it would be tiresome to copy and paste that all to Android Studio. Is it permissible to upload the minimal sample to github and provide the link?

Interesting though your observation with the back button. I didn't use that in my testing, but navigated only with the drawer and the text. I will test that as well.

"Is it permissible to upload the minimal sample to github and provide the link?" - Sure.

Remove specific argument with:
arguments?.remove(SaleFragment.BARCODE)

